# Sass selector helper for classes

Tags: sass

I often use this kind of css selector to match all classes starting by a prefix :

```
.foo [class^="bar-"],
.foo [class*=" bar-"] {
    // Somme css
}
```

I was wondering if there is a Sass function/mixin/helper that could help me doing it in one line and not write the 2 rules (^ for starting by and * for contains) ? Maybe something with a function like :

```
.foo classStartBy('bar-') {
    // Somme css
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

As this may not be the best answer, you can always create a `@mixin` that accepts the needed classes that will create the wanted selector:

```
@mixin bar($classes) {
  #{$classes} {
    //your wanted CSS
    display: flex;
  }
}

.foo {
  @include bar('[class^="bar-"], [class*="bar-"]');
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.foo [class^="bar-"], .foo [class*="bar-"] {
  display: flex;
}
```

You can additionally add a second parameter to the `mixin` which can accept the CSS styles.